# Can't track applications network communication under same machine

Tags: windows, wireshark, loopback, packet-sniffer

I have a network application environment of 7 applications communicating with eachother through UDP and TCP. All of them using either the machine's local network IP or 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to listen on ports or connecting to eachother.

All these applications are running on a single test machine.

I want to analyze precisely how each application communicate with the others so I tried Wireshark and Netmon. However both Wireshark and Netmon don't show me any of the packets sent or received by any of these applications.

What can I do to analyze this environment? Does Wireshark or Netmon able to analyze that? Is there a problem tracking packets using same source and destination IP?

Comment: @anx I market all adapters available in `netmon` and tried almost all adapters available in `wireshark` and couldn't find the packets. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you say you're using NetMon, do you mean Microsoft Network Monitor? If so, it should list the processes involved in the traffic. Do you see any of your applications in the list?

Comment: @joeqwerty ye I by `netmon` I meant Microsoft Network Monitor. No, the processes are not being showed in the traffic list. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Are the applications running? If they are then they're not generating any traffic.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes they are up and running and sending packets to eachother, yet I can't even see them in the process list. I was reading something about a incapacity of these tools to analyze loopback or connections running under the same NIC? I'm very new to these networking concepts so I'm probably missing something big here.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback